# How may I prevent content from moving down upon expanding a <details> tag?

Tags: css

I'm still trying to get the hang of `<details>` and I've run into a snag that I know has a very obvious answer, but... it's late, I'm stupid, and I *cannot* figure it out.

How do I prevent a div from moving to accommodate an expanded details tag, like in the instance of the red div in the following snippet?

```css
.test {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Summary Test</summary>
  <ul>
  <li>Thing #1</li>
    <li>Thing #1</li>
      <li>Thing #1</li>
  </ul>
</details>
<div class="test">
Test
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want the details content to overlap the div?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the problem statement, this will do the job.

```
.test {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top:26px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

`position:absolute` -  Will fix it to the parent (in the snippet the parent is `body` element), you can adjust the position.

`top:26px;` -  I am setting the position from the top of the parent to `26px`, you can also set `left`, `right`, `bottom`

`z-index:-1` - If you want the absolute element to be behind the dropdown, you need to set this property and the dropdown will show above the div with class `test`

```css
.test {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Summary Test</summary>
  <ul>
    <li>Thing #1</li>
    <li>Thing #1</li>
    <li>Thing #1</li>
  </ul>
</details>
<div class="test">
  Test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like a folding menu, you can set the folding part in absolute position

```css
.test {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  }
  details {
  position:relative;/* reference for absolute child */
  background:tomato;
  }
  summary + ul {
  margin:0;/* reset margin to stick to summary*/
  position:absolute;/* take it off the flow to not disturb the layout */
  background:inherit;/* make sure background is there too and .test hidden underneath*/
  }
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Summary Test</summary>
  <ul>
  <li>Thing #1</li>
    <li>Thing #1</li>
      <li>Thing #1</li>
  </ul>
</details>
<div class="test">
Test
</div>
```

or set an height to details and let overflow be visible

```css
.test {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  }
  details {
  height:1.4em;
  position:relative;/* keep it on top */
  background:tomato;
  }
  summary + ul {
  margin:0;
  background:inherit;
  }
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Summary Test</summary>
  <ul>
  <li>Thing #1</li>
    <li>Thing #1</li>
      <li>Thing #1</li>
  </ul>
</details>
<div class="test">
Test
</div>
```